# Trim multiple characters using php

Tags: php

How to trim multiple characters at begin and end of string.
string should be something like `{Hello {W}orld}`.
i want to trim both `{` and `}` at begin and end.

don't want to use multiple `trim` function.

Comment: You can provide an optional charlist to the `trim` function, as the [manual explains](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). *Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped. With .. you can specify a range of characters.*

Comment: thank you, just don't know why people are voting down

Comment: I assume that all initial downvotes were because you were asking a very simple question which could have been avoided if you simply cracked open the freely available online php manual.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the optional second argument to [`trim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which allows you to specify the list of characters to trim:

```
<?php
$str = "{Hello {W}orld}";
$str = trim($str, "{}");

echo "Trimmed: $str";
```

Output:

```
Trimmed: Hello {W}orld
```

Answer (score -3):

Is there always a character at the beginning and at the end, that you want to remove? If so you could just use the following:

```
<?php
$string = '{Hello {W}orld}';
echo substr( $string, 1, strlen( $string )-2 );
?>
```

See: http://codepad.org/IDbG6Km2